# Branches for a data science project

Tags: git, data-science

I have a Git repository in which I'm developing a data science project, with occasional contributions from others.
It involves

- a package I'm developing
- experiments - scripts that use the package to say something about data kept externally

Till now I have been using two branches:

- `development` - new releases of the package were prepared on this branch (e.g. API needed to be changed or new features were required)
- `master` - this always keeps the current, working release of the package, such that everyone can clone/download the package and start their own experiment

New experiments were committed just to `master`, what now I find a bit weird. Is there any better alternative? Should I create a branch `experiments`?

Comment: There really isn't a set standard. At my job master is only for production ready code (or finalized versions). Develop is for features we are ready to test cohesively, and branches off of develop are new features we are working on. This works for us, but may not work for you. It depends on what logic makes sense for you and for that reason I think this question is off topic as primarily opinion based.

Comment: I find the question very opinion based. Also, what is the harm in creating a new branch? In git it takes a second or two since git is not like other VCSs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are asking for is a workflow and branch management strategy.

Git workflows are a dime a dozen and depend largely on personal preference and team size.  I've always found the workflow comparison authored by Atlassian pretty useful for enterprise projects (available at https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows).  I personally prefer to use the Gitflow model described therein for medium sized projects.

If you have a small team and good attention to detail, you might just consider trunk-based development (https://paulhammant.com/2013/04/05/what-is-trunk-based-development/).  Or you may just have no branching strategy at all.

In your case, if you have any quality control mechanism around the "experiments" at all, you probably want to keep them out of develop/master until they are verified, which may warrant a branching strategy with tests that run via CI prior to approving pull requests.